# Rock Paper Scissors function not showing up

Tags: python

The function is not working and therefore my score is not adding. I would like to run this just like a normal rock paper scissors game. It would be highly appreciated if you are able to solve this problem.

```
import random

user_score = 0
computer_score = 0


def Choose_Option():
    user_choice = input("Choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")
    if user_choice in ["Rock", "rock", "r", "R"]:
        user_choice = "r"
    elif user_choice in ["Paper", "paper", "p", "P"]:
        user_choice = "p"
    elif user_choice in ["Scissors", "scissors", "s", "S"]:
        user_choice = "s"
    else:
        print("I don't understand. Try Again")
        Choose_option()
    return user_choice

def Computer_Option():
    computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
    if computer_choice == 1:
        computer_choice == "r"
    elif computer_choice == 2:
        computer_choice == "p"
    else:
        computer_choice == "s"
    return computer_choice

while True:
    print("")

    user_choice = Choose_Option()
    computer_choice = Computer_Option()

    print("")

    if user_choice == "r":
        if computer_choice == "r":
            print("You choose rock. Computer choose rock. Tied")

        elif computer_choice == "p":
            print("You choose rock. Computer choose paper. You Lose")
            computer_score += 1

        elif computer_choice == "s":
            print("You choose rock. Computer choose scissors. You Win")
            user_score += 1

    elif user_choice == "p":
        if computer_choice == "p":
            print("You choose paper. Computer choose paper. Tied")

        elif computer_choice == "r":
            print("You choose paper. Computer choose rock. You Win")
            user_score += 1

        elif computer_choice == "s":
            print("You choose paper. Computer choose scissors. You lose")
            computer_score += 1

    elif user_choice == "s":
        if computer_choice == "s":
            print("You choose scissors. Computer choose scissors. Tied")

        elif computer_choice == "r":
            print("You choose scissors. Computer choose rock. You lose")
            computer_score += 1

        elif computer_choice == "p":
            print("You choose scissors. Computer choose paper. You win")
            user_score += 1

    print("")
    print("Player wins: " + str(user_score))
    print("Computer wins: " + str(computer_score))
    print("")

    user_choice = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)")
    if user_choice in ["Y", "y", "yes", "Yes", "YES"]:
        pass
    elif user_choice in ["N", "NO", "no", "No", "n"]:
        break
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Your computer choice function is not returning what you expect. You accidentally put `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Thanks @Goion for your solution. Appreciate it and once again thank you.

Comment: In the `Choose_Option()` function, when you again call the function (in line `11` of the function) :- change it from `Choose_option()` to `user_choice = Choose_Option()`

Answer (score 0):

I liked this problem. Try posting it in github as well.
Here are some improvements that I made it.

```py
import random

user_score = 0
computer_score = 0


def Choose_Option():
    user_choice = input("Choose Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")
    user_choice=user_choice.lower()
    if user_choice in ["rock", "r"]:
        user_choice = "r"
    elif user_choice in ["paper", "p"]:
        user_choice = "p"
    elif user_choice in ["scissors", "s"]:
        user_choice = "s"
    else:
        print("I don't understand. Try Again")
        Choose_Option()
    return user_choice

def Computer_Option():
    computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
    dict_option = {
        1:'r'
        ,2:'p'
        ,3:'s'
    }
    computer_choice=dict_option.get(computer_choice)
    return computer_choice

while True:
    print("")

    user_choice = Choose_Option()
    computer_choice = Computer_Option()

    print("")

    dict_rule={
    'p':'r',
    's':'p',
    'r':'s'
    }
    dict_name={
    'p':'Paper',
    's':'Scissor',
    'r':'Rock'
    }
    if user_choice==computer_choice:
        print(f"You choose {dict_name[user_choice]}. Computer choose {dict_name[computer_choice]}. Tied")

    elif dict_rule[user_choice] == computer_choice:
        print(f"You choose {dict_name[user_choice]}. Computer choose {dict_name[computer_choice]}. You Win")
        user_score += 1
    else:
        print(f"You choose {dict_name[user_choice]}. Computer choose {dict_name[computer_choice]}. You Lose")
        computer_score += 1

    print("")
    print("Player wins: " + str(user_score))
    print("Computer wins: " + str(computer_score))
    print("")

    user_choice = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)")
    user_choice=user_choice.lower()
    if user_choice in ["y", "yes"]:
        pass
    elif user_choice in ["no","n"]:
        break
    else:
        break
```